# Cryptic "row value misused" error with sqlite prepared statements on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I'm writing a simple model wrapper, and two of my prepared statements won't compile. The language is javascript (nodejs), using `sqlite3`. Both of the statements are delete operations, and I can't figure out what's wrong with them. All of the other statements (create read update) compile fine.

Here is the lines

```
this[CacheSymbol].deleteSettings = await this.driver.prepare(`DELETE FROM Model_Settings`)
this[CacheSymbol].deleteSettingByName = await this.driver.prepare(`DELETE FROM Model_Settings WHERE key = ?`)
```

Both of them fail (I've tried commenting out one and the other) with the same error: `SQLITE_ERROR: row value misused`.

For completeness, here's the whole function:

```
async statements() {
    if(!this[CacheSymbol]) {
        this[CacheSymbol] = {}  
        this[CacheSymbol].insertBooleanSetting = await this.driver.prepare(`INSERT INTO Model_Settings (key,valueType,booleanValue) VALUES (?,0,?)`)
        this[CacheSymbol].insertIntegerSetting = await this.driver.prepare(`INSERT INTO Model_Settings (key,valueType,integerValue) VALUES (?,0,?)`)
        this[CacheSymbol].insertDoubleSetting = await this.driver.prepare(`INSERT INTO Model_Settings (key,valueType,doubleValue) VALUES (?,0,?)`)
        this[CacheSymbol].insertStringSetting = await this.driver.prepare(`INSERT INTO Model_Settings (key,valueType,stringValue) VALUES (?,0,?)`)
        this[CacheSymbol].insertBufferSetting = await this.driver.prepare(`INSERT INTO Model_Settings (key,valueType,bufferValue) VALUES (?,0,?)`)
        this[CacheSymbol].getAllSettings = await this.driver.prepare(`SELECT * FROM  Model_Settings`)
        this[CacheSymbol].getSettingsByName = await this.driver.prepare(`SELECT * FROM Model_Settings WHERE key = ?`)
        this[CacheSymbol].updateBooleanSettingByName = await this.driver.prepare(`UPDATE Model_Settings SET booleanValue = ? WHERE key = ?`)
        this[CacheSymbol].updateIntegerSettingByName = await this.driver.prepare(`UPDATE Model_Settings SET integerValue = ? WHERE key = ?`)
        this[CacheSymbol].updateDoubleSettingByName = await this.driver.prepare(`UPDATE Model_Settings SET doubleValue = ? WHERE key = ?`)
        this[CacheSymbol].updateStringSettingByName = await this.driver.prepare(`UPDATE Model_Settings SET stringValue = ? WHERE key = ?`)
        this[CacheSymbol].updateBufferSettingByName = await this.driver.prepare(`UPDATE Model_Settings SET bufferValue = ? WHERE key = ?`)
        this[CacheSymbol].deleteSettings = await this.driver.prepare(`DELETE FROM Model_Settings`)
        this[CacheSymbol].deleteSettingByName = await this.driver.prepare(`DELETE FROM Model_Settings WHERE key = ?`)
    }
    return this[CacheSymbol]
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? How do I fix this? Any and all help greatly appreciated

**EDIT**

I tried this in node REPL using `sqlite3` directly (none of my wrappers), and I get the same error. I'm thinking it might be to do with a trigger I have set, so I'll add the whole table definition.

settings.model.sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Model_Settings (
    key TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    valueType TEXT NOT NULL,
    booleanValue INTEGER,
    integerValue INTEGER,
    doubleValue REAL,
    stringValue TEXT,
    bufferValue BLOB,
    lastUpdate DATETIME
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_Model_Settings_key ON Model_Settings (key);
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS Model_Settings_trigger_update_timestamp AFTER UPDATE ON Model_Settings 
BEGIN
    UPDATE Model_Settings SET lastUpdate = DATETIME('NOW') WHERE key = NEW.key;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS Model_Settings_trigger_insert_timestamp AFTER INSERT ON Model_Settings 
BEGIN
    UPDATE Model_Settings SET lastUpdate = DATETIME('NOW') WHERE key = NEW.key;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS Model_Settings_trigger_insert_valueType BEFORE INSERT ON Model_Settings
BEGIN
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN NEW.valueType NOT IN (0,1,2,3,4) THEN
                RAISE ( ABORT, 'Invalid valueType for Setting' )
        END;
END;
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS Model_Settings_trigger_delete_valueType BEFORE DELETE ON Model_Settings
BEGIN
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN OLD.valueType NOT IN ((0,1,2,3,4)) THEN
                RAISE ( ABORT, 'Invalid valueType for Setting' )
        END;
END;
```

**Another Edit**
So, here's a script that can be run (along with the above sql) to reproduce the error (hopefully it's not just me)

```
const Sqlite3 = require('sqlite3')
const database = new Sqlite3.Database(':memory:')
database.exec(require('fs').readFileSync(require('path').resolve(__dirname,'./server/lib/model/settings.model.sql'),{encoding: 'utf8'}))
//above line loads sql as string
database.prepare(`DELETE FROM Model_Settings`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm a dunce. Further up in execution, the generator that produced the sql file left in an extra set of parenthesis, and I was too blind to see it. So, to answer:

The `Model_Settings_trigger_delete_valueType` trigger had an extra set of parenthesis left around `(0,1,2,3,4)`, a bug that occurred days before when I generated these sql files (from my own, bugged out, script), but wasn't noticed until I started running tests. The moral of the story is, program [defensively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming), and assume bugs are your own before you assume otherwise. Thanks everyone, I hope this can serve as an iron boot, and others won't foot-shoot as much as I